# My bash script that works in terminal does not work when run as a script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, web-scraping

I have a simple bash script that goes to a webpage and scrapes the first installment of the Harry Potter novels and replaces each instance of "wand" with "butt."  At the end, I wish to print the modified novel to the console but the script just halts and does not end.  However, when I run each command separately in the terminal, the code works fine.  I'm not sure what it is about running the actual .sh file that causes the final code to not run.

I know that the script runs up until the final echo command because it successfully creates the two output files.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone
touch output_file.txt
curl 'https://archive.org/stream/joannek.rowlingharrypotterbook1harrypotterandthephilosophersstoneenglishonlineclub.com/Joanne%20K.%20Rowling%20%28Harry%20Potter%2C%20Book%201%29%20-%20Harry%20Potter%20and%20the%20Philosophers%20Stone%20%5BEnglishOnlineClub.com%5D_djvu.txt' -o "output_file.txt"

tr "\n" "|" < output_file.txt | grep -o '<pre>.*</pre>' | sed 's/\(<pre>\|<\/pre>\)//g;s/|/\n/g' > parsed_output.txt
harry1=$( sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' parsed_output.txt )

harry1_butt="${harry1//wand/butt}"
harry1_butt="${harry1_butt//buttering/wandering}"

echo "$harry1_butt"


exit
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: The script worked fine for me, but I would try removing the `exit` at the end since that will close the shell it is running in, so if it ran using `source` it will close your own shell. If it is ran in a subshell then the subshell should close automatically without the need for `exit`.